# Sending Mail Fail with NDR '554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Deliver.Exception:ObjectNotFoundException'

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

there is a problem in sending some mails to one user, some random mails sent normally to any recipient expect one user, which return a NDR as follow

> Remote Server returned '554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Deliver.Exception:ObjectNotFoundException.MapiExceptionNotFound; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message The process failed to get the correct properties. 16.55847:E1040000, 17.43559:000000002E010000000000000000000000000000, 20.52176:010F80880C00103100000000, 20.50032:010F80887C17000000000000, 0.35180:010F8088, 255.23226:75010000, 255.27962:02000000, 255.17082:0F010480, 0.21857:14000000, 4.21921:0F010480, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:80030400, 0.44680:05000780, 8.45434:8DE63CC31F0C9E479A6B920D61D0A54800000000, 5.10786:0000000031352E30312E323137362E3031323A5359532D45584730322D5052442D573A34343632363739322D643739622D343663362D396539362D3537633632633930303336320000000000, 255.1750:00000000, 255.27962:06000000, 255.17082:B9040000, 0.24929:00000780, 4.21921:B9040000, 255.27962:A1000000, 255.17082:B9040000, 0.27745:0F010480, 4.21921:B9040000, 255.27962:07000000, 0.26881:3837372D, 255.21817:B9040000, 0.20385:65312D32, 4.28577:0F010480, 0.32001:05000780, 4.29953:0F010480, 0.32768:A1000000, 4.33024:0F010480 [Stage: CreateMessage]'

and to solve the problem we just make any modification to the mail subject and it sent successfully (i.e. add a space to the mail subject)

Did any one face this problem before

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been documented in this link
[STOREDRV.Deliver.Exception:ObjectNotFoundException.MapiExceptionNotFound - Exchange | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/email-delivery/mapiexceptionnotfound-ndr)

It says the issue occurs if the Clutter feature is enabled for the user but the Clutter folder is missing in the user's mailbox.
You may need to disable Clutter for the user, then check if the issue still persist.

1.In Outlook on the web, click Settings in the upper-right corner.

2.Click My app settings, click Mail, and then click Clutter.

3.Clear the Separate items identified as clutter check box, and then click Save.

Comment: we don't have the clutter feature in our environment, we have exchange servers 2016

Answer (score 0):

The issue may occur with the database.

Try creating a new database and then move a mailbox in it to test.

If the issue still persist, run below command to fix it.

```
New-MailboxRepairRequest -Mailbox username -CorruptionType ProvisionedFolder,SearchFolder,AggregateCounts,Folderview -Archive
```

Comment: Hi, is there any update? If the issue has been resolved, please mark the helpful replies as answers, this will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well.

Comment: This one will no longer be the goto command since this could create bigger issues than solutions on Exo backend.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer I could have found
https://cloudbrothers.info/en/the-case-of-mapiexceptionshutoffquotaexceeded/#delete-the-affected-item